# How to join two different array values and create csv file in php

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv, fgetcsv

Here is my task

```
$value1= ['apple', 'ball', 'cat', 'dog'];
$value2= ['elephant', 'frog', 'griffee', 'honeybee'];
$value3 = [1,3,4,5];
```

I want to create a csv file by combining this two different array.

```
$fp = fopen('sample.csv', 'w');

foreach ( $value as $values ) {
   $val1 = explode(",", $values1);  
   fputcsv($fp, $val1);
}
fclose($fp);
```

and output of csv should be apple, elephant

```
                            ball, frog, 1    
                            cat, griffee, 3
                            dog, honeybee, 4
```

I am getting only single column. if i join two array it's showing error.

Can any one help me how to solve this problem. Thanks you and all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: RTFM: [fputcsv](http://php.net/fputcsv) the 2nd argument is expected to be an ARRAY. you're not passing in an array, you're passing in a STRING.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay close attention to the variable names you use, you have several typos. That being said. Try this code

```
$value1 = ['apple', 'ball', 'cat', 'dog'];
$value2 = ['elephant', 'frog', 'griffee', 'honeybee'];

$fp = fopen('sample.csv', 'w');

for ( $i = 0; $i < count($value1) - 1; ++$i) {
   fputcsv($fp, array($value1[$i], $value2[$i]));
}

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thanks it's working fine. But if i have more than two arrays it's adding only two values.

Comment: you are constructing the one row here array($value1[$i], $value2[$i]). you can keep adding more values to the array... eg: array($value1[$i], $value2[$i], $value3[$i])